# Is parameter tying more common in RNNs than in regular NNs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

From what I can see it seems like RNNs favour using a backprop through time method which I haven't seen really applied to other neural networks.

Can someone explain the significance of tying the weights and why it is necessary to be done for backprop  through time?